# Movie where serial killer puts all the women he kills in the water like a "underwater garden"

Tags: identify-this-movie, thriller, crime

The film is about this policeman, who tries to help one victim, who managed to escape from serial killer. If I remember correctly she had red hair and is really afraid of water.

At the end of the movie, the killer gets to her, threw her in the lake in a red dress (with her feet stuck in a block of cement). Also killer threw in the like other dead women. I think the killer says, that the women in the lake are his garden or something like that.

The policeman discovers where she is, saves her by placing a decoy mannequin in her place with a camera. But the killer gets suspicious, and he went after both of them. The policeman and the women "kills" the killer (I think she shoots him), and everything is alright.

Good guy gets the girl, and he takes her to a lake (or river) so she can get past her panic of water, and for a while she is happy and carefree with the dude, but in a flash she sees the killer underwater and she panics. It ends with her crying in the cop's arms, and the image of the killer underwater smiling.

The movie is probably from the end of the 90's or early 00's. The movie should be in English language (watched with dubbed voice).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like TV movie [Cabin by the Lake](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0199389/combined) from 2000.

> A screenwriter does research for his new script by actually kidnapping and drowning young girls. He then places them in his "garden" of other dead girls coming back daily to check on them. One girl narrowly escapes and the other bodies are found leading to an ingenious plot to try and capture the killer.

Everything you described happened there, including the ending where she has visions of the killer (played by Judd Nelson) and her fear of water. Here's the trailer:

Comment: Welcome back !!

Comment: Thank you so very much!I have to confess that in my head this movie was waay scary.. I even wasn't that young, but a kid imagination is a wonder, huh? Thank you again!